# Pycord Delete Slash Message Command Respond

Tags: python-3.x, discord, pycord

I am making a Discord python bot and I have a Message Slash command implemented with

```
@bot.message_command(name="TestCmd", guild_ids=[id])
async def hello(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.respond("Hello!")
```

When running the code I am able to "right-click" on a message and I see and can run the "TestCmd" command. When I click it the bot responds with the message "Hello"

I would like the Message slash command to not actually have a response, but since discord requires slash commands to have a response I was hoping to be able to delete it right after responding.

Adding code like this

```
await msg.delete()
```

or

```
await msg.deleteResponse()
```

does not work. Is there any way to be able to delete the 'ctx.respond()' message?

The only option I have found so far is to use "ctx.respond(..., ephemeral=True)" which will only display the response to the user which triggered the slash command.

Is there anyway to clear the response?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the response after a set amount of time. In your case that would be 0 seconds.

Here's the code you need:

```
await ctx.respond("Hello!", delete_after=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can response to the message as ephemeral so it only shows to the user and they have the ability to dismiss the message.